# How to get attribut value from xml element?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following xml which I take from specified url:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>...</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>...</gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2016-08-16">
           <Cube value="1" />
           <Cube value="2"/>
           <Cube value="3"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

From this file I only need to take time value '2016-08-16' using Visual Basic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim _date As DateTime = CType(doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) (x.Name.LocalName = "Cube") And (Not x.Attribute("time") Is Nothing)).Select(Function(x) x.Attribute("time")).FirstOrDefault(), DateTime)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these imports:

```
Imports <xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01">
Imports <xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
```

Then load your data however you wish into an XDocument or XElement

```
Dim xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("myxml.xml")
```

The query it as follows. (if you're using XElement don't include Root).

```
Dim time = xmlDoc.Root.<Cube>.<Cube>.@time
```

Comment: If you use an `XDocument` you need to access the `Root` property first (and I'm not sure the `Load` will work without an xml declaration on the sample). OTOH you can use an `XElement` instead

Comment: Thanks @Sehnsucht I've added the missing Root. I developed it using XElement and then got caught out with the shortcut.